# Pagination algorithm based on scores

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, pagination

I need to divide `scoreResult` into pages (which is already ordered by score column from highest to lowest), and each page cannot contain too many records (e.g. 12 is a limitation in my example), and each page cannot contain duplicate `id1`, and each page needs to be ordered by score from highest to lowest.

Here is my working code; I am seeking advice, especially of smarter and more efficient solutions.

```
scoreResult = [
#id1,id2,score",
"1,28,300.1",
"4,5,209.1",
"20,7,208.1",
"23,8,207.1",
"16,10,206.1",
"1,16,205.1",
"1,31,204.6",
"6,29,204.1",
"7,20,203.1",
"8,21,202.1",
"2,18,201.1",
"2,30,200.1",
"15,27,109.1",
"10,13,108.1",
"11,26,107.1",
"12,9,106.1",
"13,1,105.1",
"22,17,104.1",
"1,2,103.1",
"28,24,102.1",
"18,14,11.1",
"6,25,10.1",
"19,15,9.1",
"3,19,8.1",
"3,11,7.1",
"27,12,6.1",
"1,3,5.1",
"25,4,4.1",
"5,6,3.1",
"29,22,2.1",
"30,23,1.1"
]

PageLimit = 12

def pageResult():

    #store final resutls
    pages = {}
    # store dictionary to see if page exists
    # key = host_id+#+page_id, value = item
    pageDict = {}
    # key: page ID, value: # of items
    pageCount = {}
    for item in scoreResult:
        page= 0
        host_id=item.split(',')[0]

        while pageDict.has_key(str(host_id)+'#'+str(page)) or (pageCount.has_key(page) and pageCount[page] >= PageLimit):
            #print page
            page += 1
        pageDict[str(host_id)+'#'+str(page)] = True
        if pages.has_key(page):
            pages[page].append(item)
        else:
            pages[page]=[]
            pages[page].append(item)

        if pageCount.has_key(page):
            pageCount[page] += 1
        else:
            pageCount[page] = 1

    for k,v in pages.items():
        print k
        print v

if __name__=="__main__":
    pageResult()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at your code you have a lot of `if pageCount.has_key(page): else:`.
This can be replaced with a `defaultdict`.
`pages` defaults to a list, as if `pages[page]` does not exist you manually default it to a list.
And `page_count` defaults to zero.

As a simple example the following is how you could use default-dicts:

```
from collections import defaultdict

pages = defaultdict(list)
pages[0].append('Page 1')
```

I think changing `page_dict` to a `set` would be better, as they index the same way, but using a `set` will use less memory.

I would use a tuple as `page_dict`'s key, rather than a string.
This is as `(a, b)` is easier to read than `str(a) + "#" + str(b)`.

Python also has a style guide called [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which basically means that your variables should be `snake_case`, and `PageLimit` should be `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE` as it's a constant.

---

Using the above should get you:

```
def page_result(score_result):
    pages = defaultdict(list)
    page_dict = set()
    page_count = defaultdict(int)
    for item in score_result:
        page = 0
        host_id = item.split(',')[0]

        while (host_id, page) in page_dict or page_count[page] >= PAGE_LIMIT:
            page += 1

        pages[page].append(item)
        page_dict.add((host_id, page))
        page_count[page] += 1

    for k, v in pages.items():
        print k
        print v
```

---

You could make another default-dict to store the latest page for a `host_id`.

This limits the amount of times the while loop runs. This *dramatically* reduces the amount of time it takes on larger data-sets. *But* has little diffrence on small data sets, and can perform slower!

I use the same data as given in the question, but timesed by 100.
`scoreResult *= 100`.

This gave me the following times, over 1000 tries:

- Original: 225.99s
- My original: 53.14s
- My updatet: 2.97s
- Mathias': 58.83s

This shows that there may be little speed-up from using a dictionary rather than `len`.
I also removed the prints.

---

```
def page_result(score_result):
    pages = defaultdict(list)
    page_dict = set()
    page_count = defaultdict(int)
    host_page = defaultdict(int)
    for item in score_result:
        host_id = item.split(',')[0]
        page = host_page[host_id]

        while page_count[page] >= PAGE_LIMIT:
            page += 1

        pages[page].append(item)
        page_dict.add((host_id, page))
        page_count[page] += 1
        host_page[host_id] = page + 1

    for k, v in pages.items():
        print k
        print v
```

---

I would also recommend:

1. Moving the `print` part of the function into it's own function.
2. Read the data from a file. Saving it as a JSON file and using Python's JSON library is a simple way to do this.

Comment: Thanks Joe, very cool comments. Wondering if you have ideas to improve the algorithm efficiency? I think I only did a straightforward implementation and there might be smarter ways for pagination with unique ID on each page? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa I can think of a way... But I think it's a premature optimisation... But here I go, to see if it is plausible

Comment: Hi Joe, what is your optimization method? Want to learn from you.

Comment: @LinMa I updated the answer with it. I'm still shocked at how much of a change it makes...

Comment: thanks and wondering if this is your update -- "You could make another default-dict to store the latest page for a host_id."? Do not know how to track changed part on SO, so confirm with you. :)

Comment: @LinMa Yes from that to "I would also recommend:" If you are having a hard time telling, you may want to press the "edited x minutes ago", the removals will be in red, where the additions will be in green.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I think your new version of code is much smarter. Wondering if you have ideas to improve the algorithm efficiency a further more -- I am thinking maybe we can leverage the score result already sorted feature for more optimization for efficiency? Have a good weekend. :)

Comment: BTW Joe, another question is, in your new improved version of code which uses host_page, I think there is no need to use page_dict? Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34388/discussion-between-joe-wallis-and-lin-ma).

Answer (score 4):

## A function has parameters

It allows for more flexibility and reusability. There is absolutely no need to declare `scoreResult` as a global variable, it forces you to use that variable name each time you want to use this function. Instead declare it as a parameter of the function.

Same goes for `PageLimit`; except for this one you can use a default value to avoid specifying it each time. Something along the lines of:

```
def pageResult(data, PageLimit=12):
    # Do your stuff here
```

## A function can return data

Especially a function altering input data such as yours. Functions should essentially perform one task and let other tasks to the rest of the program. Your function performs the pagination. Period. Let the pretty printing to someone else.

If you `return pages` at the end of your function, you can have your "main" par looks like:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    scoreResult = [
        #id1,id2,score",
        "1,28,300.1",
        "4,5,209.1",
        # snip
        "30,23,1.1"
    ]

    pages = pageResult(scoreResult)
    for k, v in pages.items():
        print k
        print v
```

This let you change the way you print (or even use) your result without modifying the behaviour of your function.

## Checking for keys in dictionaries

`some_dict.has_key(something)` [is deprecated](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.has_key): use `something in some_dict` instead.

You also use `pageDict` only to check the existence of specific keys in it, never using the associated values. The whole purpose of `pageDict[str(host_id) + '#' + str(page)] = True` is only to create the key, not to store a value: use a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) instead. You can use it pretty similarly:

```
while str(host_id) + '#' + str(page) in pageDict ...:
    page += 1
pageDict.add(str(host_id) + '#' + str(page))
```

## Getting values out of dictionaries

Checking if a key exist in a dictionary and, if it does, retrieve its value is so common in Python that you have three ways of doing it:

- using some kind of `if ... else` such as in your `while` loop;
- accessing the value directly with the key and catching the `KeyError` if it didn't exist (preferred when failures are expected to be low);
- using the [`get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method which does the latter in one line.

`get` even allows to retrieve a default value if the key doesn't exist. Which you can use to simplify your `while`:

```
while str(host_id) + '#' + str(page) in pageDict or pageCount.get(page, 0) >= PageLimit:
```

In the same vein, creating a default value for a key or retrieving the existing value has been implemented in the [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method:

```
pages.setdefault(page, []).append(item)
count = pageCount.setdefault(page, 0)
pageCount[page] = count + 1
```

## Use proper data-structures

Converting data to a string for comparison purposes is not the way to go. You are both loosing meaning and time for comparisons. You'd better of use tuples instead.

And speaking of meaning, why not convert your ids into integers first:

```
page = 0
host_id = int(item.split(',')[0])
while (host_id, page) in pageDict or pageCount.get(page, 0) >= PageLimit:
    page += 1
# We add a tuple here, hence the double parenthesis
pageDict.add((host_id, page))
```

Additionally, the number of items stored for a single page can be found using the length of the list of items of this specific page. Thus, you don't need `pageCount` at all:

```
while (host_id, page) in pageDict or len(pages.get(page, [])) >= PageLimit:
    page += 1
# We add a tuple here, hence the double parenthesis
pageDict.add((host_id, page))
pages.setdefault(page, []).append(item)
```

Lastly, you can simplify the use of `get` and `setdefault` on `pages` by turning this dictionary into a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict). It lets you specify a constructor for default values when building the dictionary. Each access to a key that has not been defined before will create the associated values using this constructor, thus no need to specify each time using either `get` or `setdefault`. Example:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d['test']
[]
>>> d['again'].append(1)
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'test': [], 'again': [1]})
```

## A note on style

The official Python style guide is [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Out of it, note:

- the use of *snake_case* instead of *camelCase* or *TitleCase* for variables or functions naming;
- the use of a space before and after the `=` in an assignment (except for specifying default values of parameters);
- the use of a space after comas.

You should also try to come with better, more explicit, names instead of `pageXXX`.

## Proposed improvement

```
from collections import defaultdict


def paginate(data, page_limit=12):
    pages = defaultdict(list)
    ids_in_page = set()

    for item in data:
        page = 0
        host_id = int(item.split(',')[0])

        # Find the page where the id is not already in that page
        # and which still has room in it.
        while (host_id, page) in ids_in_page or len(pages[page]) >= page_limit:
            page += 1

        # We add a tuple here, hence the double parenthesis
        ids_in_page.add((host_id, page))

        pages[page].append(item)

    return pages


if __name__=="__main__":
    score_result = [
        #id1,id2,score",
        "1,28,300.1",
        "4,5,209.1",
        "20,7,208.1",
        "23,8,207.1",
        "16,10,206.1",
        "1,16,205.1",
        "1,31,204.6",
        "6,29,204.1",
        "7,20,203.1",
        "8,21,202.1",
        "2,18,201.1",
        "2,30,200.1",
        "15,27,109.1",
        "10,13,108.1",
        "11,26,107.1",
        "12,9,106.1",
        "13,1,105.1",
        "22,17,104.1",
        "1,2,103.1",
        "28,24,102.1",
        "18,14,11.1",
        "6,25,10.1",
        "19,15,9.1",
        "3,19,8.1",
        "3,11,7.1",
        "27,12,6.1",
        "1,3,5.1",
        "25,4,4.1",
        "5,6,3.1",
        "29,22,2.1",
        "30,23,1.1",
    ]

    pages = paginate(score_result)
    for k, v in pages.items():
        print(k)
        print(v)
```

## A quick note on input data

I already stated that using string to store data remove the meaning associated to them. I don't know where you get your input from, neither what you plan to do with your output, but I have the feeling that you'll spend some time converting back-and-forth between strings and numerical values.

You'd better of using tuples of number if you can do so:

```
score_result = [
    #id1, id2, score
    (1, 28, 300.1),
    (4, 5, 209.1),
    (20, 7, 208.1),
    (23, 8, 207.1),
    (16, 10, 206.1),
    (1, 16, 205.1),
    (1, 31, 204.6),
    (6, 29, 204.1),
    (7, 20, 203.1),
    (8, 21, 202.1),
    (2, 18, 201.1),
    (2, 30, 200.1),
    (15, 27, 109.1),
    (10, 13, 108.1),
    (11, 26, 107.1),
    (12, 9, 106.1),
    (13, 1, 105.1),
    (22, 17, 104.1),
    (1, 2, 103.1),
    (28, 24, 102.1),
    (18, 14, 11.1),
    (6, 25, 10.1),
    (19, 15, 9.1),
    (3, 19, 8.1),
    (3, 11, 7.1),
    (27, 12, 6.1),
    (1, 3, 5.1),
    (25, 4, 4.1),
    (5, 6, 3.1),
    (29, 22, 2.1),
    (30, 23, 1.1),
]
```

This lets you retrieve the host id using `host_id = item[0]` instead of `int(item.split(',')[0])`.

Comment: Very very cool, Mathias!! Love al the comments you give. Wondering if you have ideas to improve the algorithm efficiency? I think I only did a straightforward implementation and there might be smarter ways for pagination with unique ID on each page? Thanks.

Comment: You could try grouping by ID before dispatching on pages to try to balance them. I may update the answer if I come with something when I have more time.

Comment: Thanks Mathias, there are million level of IDs (pretty unique), and wondering if we could find a way to group by efficiently? Your advice is appreciated. :)

Comment: *"# We add a tuple here, hence the double parenthesis'* -- tuples should always have a comma at the end: `ids_in_page.add((host_id, page,))

Comment: @rbp Why for? It is required for 1-sized tuples so the parser doesn't treat it as a single value, but for the rest it is not mandatory at all. It is _visually_ better when written on multiple line such as `score_result` but otherwise I don't get the reasonning.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992559/python-tuple-trailing-comma-syntax-rule

Comment: @rbp So what's more that what I said? It's better for multiline tuples/list and only required for 1-element tuples.

Comment: Hi Mathias, if you could also response to my question, it will be great -- "there are million level of IDs (pretty unique), and wondering if we could find a way to group by efficiently? Your advice is appreciated"? :)